# How to remove first and last character of a string in C#?

Tags: c#

```
String: "hello to the very tall person I am about to meet"
```

What I want it to become is this:

```
String: hello to the very tall person I am about to meet
```

I can only find code to trim the start?

Comment: Do you want to remove the “first and last character” or do you want to remove surrounding quotes? Those are different questions.

Comment: in your example, you are removing the quotes. is that the real purpose here?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

If you want to remove any first and last character from the string, then use Substring as suggested by Anish, but if you just want to remove quotes from beginning and the end, just use

```
myStr = myStr.Trim('"');
```

Note: This will remove all leading and trailing occurrences of quotes ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim)).

Comment: Just a quick warning (since it seems people are still viewing this question): if a string starts or ends with multiple quotation marks, those will also be removed, which may not be intended (question title = first and last character). E.G. ""hello world"" => hello world, rather than "hello world"

Comment: Thanks, was looking for exactly this, seems better than my solution that was same than Anish.

Comment: if u want to remove things like brackets u can use `Trim("()".ToCharArray())`

Answer (score 67):

Use the String.Substring method.

So, if your string is stored in a variable `mystr`, do as such:

```
mystr = mystr.Substring(1, mystr.Length - 2);
```

Comment: This takes it from the start, not the end!!

Comment: My mistake - I forgot C#'s is length based... I'm too used to Java! Instead of mystr.Length - 1, the second argument should be mystr.Length - 2. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 13):

C# 8: `myString[1..^1]`
See [Indices and ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/ranges-indexes)

Comment: This is only for arrays

Comment: @Rans indices and ranges also work for `string`

Comment: applying `[]` on a string variable opens it up for access by index as if it were a `char[]`, hence why ranges are fair game for the string type

Comment: In other words, `string` has an *indexer* property: `public char this[int index] { get; }`

Answer (score 11):

If you are trying to remove specific characters from a string, like the quotes in your example, you can use `Trim` for both start and end trimming, or `TrimStart` and `TrimEnd` if you want to trim different characters from the start and end. Pass these methods a character (or array of characters) that you want removed from the beginning and end of the string.

```
var quotedString = "\"hello\"";
var unQuotedString = quotedString.TrimStart('"').TrimEnd('"'); 

// If the characters are the same, then you only need one call to Trim('"'):
unQuotedString = quotedString.Trim('"');

Console.WriteLine(quotedString);
Console.WriteLine(unQuotedString);
```

Output:

> "hello"
>
> hello

Alternatively, you can use `Skip` and `Take` along with `Concat` to remove characters from the beginning and end of the string. This will work even for and empty string, saving you any worries about calculating string length:

```
var original = "\"hello\"";
var firstAndLastRemoved = string.Concat(original.Skip(1).Take(original.Length - 2));
```

Comment: Skip take looks quite fancy. why is it within string.concat?

Comment: @Sarfaraaz because `Take` returns an `IEnumerable` and we want to return a string.

Comment: I see. its part of System.Linq so it treats the String like IEnumerable<char>