# Remove First and Last Specific Char

Tags: c#, string

I dont know is that duplicate or not,but i not found same(maybe i not found because it got hard title)

So,i have a this string:

```
string a = "(Hello(World),World(Hello))";
```

And i need to remove a first Bracket,and last Bracket.
And get that output:

```
Hello(World),World(Hello)
```

I not need to remove first char and last.
I need to remove first specific char(bracket) and last specific char(close bracket).

That says,if string is be:

```
string a = "gyfw(Hello(World),World(Hello))";
```

Output is be:
gyfw Hello(World),World(Hello)

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42964150/how-to-remove-first-and-last-character-of-a-string-in-c): a = a.Substring(1, a.Length - 2);

Comment: We know the bracket is the last one, so `a.Substring(0, a.Length - 1)` will remove the last one. For the second part, a simple google search yielded: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141045/how-do-i-replace-the-first-instance-of-a-string-in-net

Comment: quanik,Nope,i not need to remove first and last char,like `(hello)` to `hello`.
I need to remove first bracket and last bracket,like `a(hi);` to `a hi ;`

Comment: FrankerZ,okay that ok to Replace First Bracket.Can explan how to remove last?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove first specific char:

```
a = a.Remove(a.IndexOf("("), 1);
```

To remove last specific char:

```
a = a.Remove(a.LastIndexOf(")"), 1);
```

Comment: i will try,wait

Comment: that works,but only removes first bracket.
Last bracket is still not removed

Comment: @Qrai The first line removes the **first** occurrence of an **opening** bracket, the second line removes the **last** occurrence of a **closing** bracket. If that's not what you wanted, try to adjust the removed chars to your needs.

Comment: OKAY,IT WORKS NOW

Answer (score 0):

In a balanced way, it can be done with this regex

Find `@"\(((?>[^()]+|\((?<Depth>)|\)(?<-Depth>))*(?(Depth)(?!)))\)"`
Replace `@"$1"`

If it is required to have *inner parens* change the `*` to a `+`.
If it is required that it should only match once and span the string, add `^` and `$` to beginning / end respectively to the regex.

Here is the regex explained

```
 \(                            #  Match ( a open parenth
 (                             # (1 start), Capture the core, to be written back

      (?>                           # Then either match (possessively):

           [^()]+                        # Any character except parenths
        |                              # or
           \(                            # Open (  increase the paren counter
           (?<Depth> )
        |                              # or
           \)                            # Close )  decrease the paren counter
           (?<-Depth> )
      )*                            # Repeat as needed.
      (?(Depth)                     # Assert that the paren counter is at zero.
           (?!)
      )

 )                             # (1 end)
 \)                            # Match ) a closing parenth
```

Comment: Im so nub to Regex
Can u show code with find and replace functions

Regex.Find ?

Regex.Replace ?

Comment: @Qrai -  Since you've been a member for 8 months, I'm sure you know that SO is not a code writing service. So, sorry, no _code_ for you. I can give you a link to C# overview where you can navigate to code examples.

Answer (score -1):

Use the [`String.Substring()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_System_Int32_) method to remove specific character.

So, if your string is stored in a variable myval:

```
myval = myval.Substring(1, myval.Length - 1);
```

Comment: I dont understand your answer.

I need to remove a first BRACKET,not just char.
And LAST BRACKET in string,not just last char.

Comment: Easy way to your answer is:     myval.Replace(@"(", string.Empty);

Comment: Did you get this answer

Comment: that will remove all BRACKETS!
i need to remove the one first and last

Comment: Store your string into variable and then remove your brackets and then use it in your code. So, I think that will be appropriate. Try for this once